# Given $g,g^t$ in an RSA group modulo $N=pq$, is it hard to compute $g^{t^{-1}}$?

Tags: discrete-logarithm, group-theory

Suppose we have an RSA groug $G=\mathbb{Z}^{*}_{N}$, where $N=pq$ , where $p,q$ are primes. Let $g$ be a random element of $G$ and $t\in \mathbb{Z}^{*}_{N}$. Having $g$ and $g^t$, it seems to be very hard to find $g^{t^{-1}}$, supposing discrete logarithm problem (DLP) is hard. My question is that is this really hard?

In a prime order group, let's say in $\mathbb{Z}^{*}_p$ , $g^{t^{-1}}$ = $g^{p-2}$ : here we don`t have to face DLP, so finding $g^{t^{-1}}$ is easy.

Comment: Actually, in a prime order group, computing $g^{t^{-1}}$ is known to be equivalent to the computational Diffie-Hellman problem; that is believed to be a hard problem in some prime-order groups.

Comment: Just adding a reference to @poncho: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.104.3007&rep=rep1&type=pdf. However, it appears to me that the reduction works in prime-order groups where all values are generators (except for the unity). It doesn't appear to work otherwise (unless you can show that a non-negligible number are generators).

Comment: Multiplication modulo an RSA number is not a group, because multiples of $p$ and $q$ are not invertible mod $N$. RSA numbers instead form a ring.

Comment: Also, isn't this question equivalent to the RSA problem? If $t^{-1}$ exists mod $\phi(n)$, then $t$ is an RSA public exponent and $t^{-1}$ is its matching private exponent.

Answer (score 2):

I know that I am not exactly answering your question, but I am pointing you in a potentially interesting research direction. Your question is not standard in the area of discrete log and Diffie-Hellman problems since you are considering a cyclic group of order $p\cdot q$ where $p$ and $q$ are primes. (Typically, we like looking at group of prime order.)

Your question is actually asking whether you can reduce this problem to solving the discrete log problem. I don't have any answer to that, but it reminds of an old paper by Biham, Boneh and Reingold that shows that the Diffie-Hellman problem modulo $N=pq$ (for Blum integers) is actually equivalent to factoring. This isn't the same thing, but there's something similar. The paper is here: https://omereingold.files.wordpress.com/2014/10/cgdh.pdf.